# update one subelement in an arrayList index

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to update an attribute's value inside an index of an ArrayList.
Mainly, I'm trying to use the set(index,e) to try and update a subelement, but I can't seem to do it.

My first class file holds the attributes which the arrayLists holds:

```
public class GenericMissile {
float currentX;
float currentY;


//set the starting location of the missile
//X Loc
 public void setLocationX() {
     currentX =(float) Math.ceil( Math.random()*801);


    //Y Loc
}
 public void setLocationY() {
     currentY = -100;

 }
}
```

the other class looks like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameManager {
ArrayList<GenericMissile> allM;


public static void main(String[] args) {
GameManager obj = new GameManager();
//create missiles
obj.createMissiles();

}
//add missile to arrayList
void createMissiles() {
//create arraylist of 25 Missiles

allM = new ArrayList<>();
GenericMissile build = new GenericMissile();
for(int i=0;i<25;i++) {
build.setLocationX();
build.setLocationY();
allM.add(build);
}
}   
}
```

I want to update one subelement from an index, however, I don't know how to go about calling the specific attribute in order to update it.

I've tried using allM.set(0,___) but I don't know the proper syntax to update currentY attribute from the GenericMissile class.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `ArrayList.set()` method for that. Instead you can get the object by calling `ArrayList.get(int index)` and mutate the returned object. It will reflect the changes inside the `ArrayList` as well. e.g.

```
allM = new ArrayList<>();
GenericMissile build = new GenericMissile();
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    build.setLocationX();
    build.setLocationY();
    allM.add(build);
}
GeneriMissile someMissile = allM.get(0);
someMissile.setLocation ... // do something with it
```

Comment: does this update the value for all of the index subelements or just the one I want?
For example, I set someMissile.currentX = 10;
does that change them all to 10 or just the set the allM.get(0) value of someMissle to 10?

Comment: @ErickP. Only the one. You might want to read more into Java tutorials since you are asking really basic questions which are the first chapter of every Java book.